# Hibernate: On SQL Server 2008 column was altered from datetime to datetime2. How I can update hibernate config to reflect this?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I have an application in which I created mappings of entities in Hibernate, so I could have access to some legacy tables on SQL Server 2005. Everything was working fine and as expected until the database was switched to a newer version of SQL Server - specifically, to SQL Server 2008.

As the data were moved, all datetime columns in tables were changed to datetime2 and now, while starting the webapp on tomcat I receive an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type (...)
Found: datetime2, expected: datetime
```

What is the proper way of changing the config in hibernate to reflect this change? All entities are defined using annotations wherever possible, all database specific c

I don't know if this is relevant but here are the versions of software which I am using:

- Hibernate 3.6.4.Final
- jTDS driver 1.2.5

Thank you very much.

### Edit: solution found

Thanks to ManuPK suggestions, I had switched from jTDS to Microsoft driver, sadly, after updating the settings of the webapp, I still received the same error. I solved it by creating custom class which is extending the `SQLServer2008Dialect` and registered `datetime2` as new column type. I don't know if this is the proper solution, but it works.

```
public class UpdatedSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2008Dialect {

   public UpdatedSQLServerDialect () {
      super();
      registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "datetime2");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have told, in MS SQL Server 2008 `datetime` is deprecated and they have added a new type `datetime2`. You can continue using the `java.lang.Date` object to map this column in the bean.

**You seems to have problem in the `SQL Driver (jTDS driver 1.2.5)` you are using. Get the new version of the `jar` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724)**. I am able to use the `datetime2` datatype with this `Jar`.

Comment: Thank you, I had switched the drivers from jTDS to the driver provided by the Microsoft, still the error didn't changed - I presume that the thing which is left to be done is changing the hibernate config to treat datetime2 as datetime. Sadly, my Google skills are not enough for that as I can't find the the solution.

Comment: Two thing there 1. the **hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect** And 2.**jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver** Get these two files latest and try. So you have got the driver correct now try to get the latest hibernate dialect.

Comment: Hi, just as I had clarified in the update to my question, I was able to use this driver but still received the same error. Thank you for pointing the way for me, I think that I managed to crack this one.