# Hibernate Date mapping to SQL Server datetime rounds by 1ms

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate-mapping, java.util.date

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and found out that mapping java.util.Date to SQL databases often causes problems and possible solutions are to

- Create own (use jodatime) hibernate UserType
- Truncate the java.util.Date before persisting on db (losing precision)

However, in all the cases I have seen, the problem was that when the date was saved, the last field (e.g. millieseconds) was lost (e.g. 000). In my case, it's a little different, consider following code:

```
public class TestDateTime implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Date created;
    private Calendar published;

    public TestDateTime(Date created, Date published) {
        this.created = created;
        this.published = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        this.published.setTime(published);
    }
}

<class name="TestDateTime" table="TestDateTime">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="created" column="created"/>
    <property name="published" column="published"/>
</class>

private void testSaveDate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    long time = 1357747095488l;

    TestDateTime tdt = new TestDateTime(new Date(time), new Date(time));

    System.out.println("Before saving created:" + tdt.getCreated().getTime() + " (" + tdt.getCreated() + ")"
        + ", published:" + tdt.getPublished().getTime().getTime() + " (" + tdt.getPublished().getTime() + ")");
    Serializable id = hibernateTemplate.save(tdt);

    TestDateTime saved = hibernateTemplate.get(TestDateTime.class, id);

    System.out.println("After saving created:" + saved.getCreated().getTime() + " (" + saved.getCreated() + ")"
        + ", published:" + saved.getPublished().getTime() + " (" + saved.getPublished() + ")");
}
```

Results in the following output on the console:

```
[INFO] Before saving created:1357747095488 (Wed Jan 09 16:58:15 CET 2013), published:1357747095488 (Wed Jan 09 16:58:15 CET 2013)
[INFO] Hibernate: insert into TestDateTime (created, published) values (?, ?)
[INFO] Hibernate: select testdateti0_.id as id42_0_, testdateti0_.created as created42_0_, testdateti0_.published as published42_0_ from TestDateTime testdateti0_ where testdateti0_.id=?
[INFO] After saving created:1357747095487 (2013-01-09 16:58:15.487), published:Wed Jan 09 16:58:15 CET 2013 (java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1357747095487,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=2,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=9,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=58,SECOND=15,MILLISECOND=487,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0])
```

So after saving the date into SQL server, it changes 1ms from **1357747095488** into **1357747095487**. Is this the expected behaviour of the datetime type of SQL Server?

Furthermore, I have to mention that the Date objects are created by JackRabbit during checkin, thus I can't truncate this date in JackRabbit, to get it synchronized with its value stored in SQL Server.

The problem is that in my application I have to compare this dates, some coming from JackRabbit and some from database (which where originally also created by jackrabbit). Since the version of the date in sql server is different then the one from JackRabbit, I can't compare them correctly.

What would be the best solution for me, that is multi database complient (we use both MySql and MsSql 2008 R2). Is there a standard way to map the java.util.Date to a bigint column, such that I can store the long value myself? Or should I create my UserType? And is this a bad idea, since I still can compare the longs in queries (and I assume Hibernate also with the proper mappings)

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of the `DateTime` data type in SQL Server is about 3ms.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  The `DateTime2` data type is more accurate.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: How can I map the field to a datetime2 column? If I just change the type of the column in sql db, hibernate complains that it needs a 'datetime' column (and not datetime2).

Comment: @user1971430 - A quick search (hibernate mapping type datetime2) turns up a variety of items.  Not being familiar with Hibernate, I'll go out on a limb and suggest [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125319/hibernate-on-sql-server-2008-column-was-altered-from-datetime-to-datetime2-how) and [this](http://robert-reiz.com/2011/05/10/sqlserver-2008-with-hibernate-3-6-4/) might be helpful re: redefining the data type mapping.